# undefined reference to vtable with inheritance

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undefined reference to vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020462/undefined-reference-to-vtable)

Running the following code is causing a linker error

`'undefined reference to vtable for ManagedObjects'`

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ManagedObjects
{
      public:
      virtual string get() const;
      virtual ~ManagedObjects(){};
};

class CallbackOwner1 : public ManagedObjects
{
public:
       string get() const {return "CallbackOwner1";} 
};

class CallbackFunctor
{
public:
    CallbackFunctor(const ManagedObjects* b):m_cbr(b)
    {}
    string operator() ()
    {
        return m_cbr->get();
    }

   const ManagedObjects* m_cbr;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ManagedObjects* cb1 = new CallbackOwner1();
    CallbackFunctor f(cb1);
    cout << f() << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: @RaymondChen indeed it is, there are many questions with the exactly same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not define the `virtual string ManagedObjects::get() const` method anywhere. Either define it as a pure virtual function `virtual string get() const = 0;` or provide a declaration for it.

Comment: Ahh Thank you! I don't know how I missed that

Comment: Read here: http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#vtables - the vtable is generated wherever the first virtual non-inline method is declared. In case that you had declared both get() and methodX() (in that order), with definitions elsewhere, had a definition for get() but no definition for methodX, the error message would have been much saner.